# How to retrieve object from firebase?

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in angular and firebase. I having problem to retrieve nested object from firebase. Here's my code.
**Controller**

```
 var rootRef = new Firebase('https://ayobacaalkitab.firebaseio.com/');
    var childUsers = rootRef.child('users');
    var childDate = rootRef.child('tanggal');
    var rekapId = $stateParams.rekapId;

    console.log(rekapId);
    childDate.child(rekapId).child('tanggalBaca').on('value',function(snap){       
        $timeout(function() {
            var snapshot= snap.val();
            $scope.tanggal = snapshot;          
            myAfterFunction();
         });
    })
    function myAfterFunction(){
    console.log($scope.tanggal);   
   
   var dates = $scope.tanggal;
   console.log(dates);
   var rekapUsers = childUsers.on('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
           $scope.keyuser = childSnapshot.key();           
            stat();      
        })
        var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();      
        $scope.users =snapshotVal;
        console.log($scope.users);
    })
    function stat(){
        var keyusers =$scope.keyuser;
        var childStatus = childUsers.child(keyusers+'/status/'+dates);      
        $scope.statusbaca = $firebaseArray(childStatus); 
        console.log($scope.statusbaca);           
        console.log(keyusers);
        })
    }
   
    }
```

**Template HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat= "item in users">
            <div class="list card" style="padding:1%;">
                <div class="col-50" style="float:left;">
                
                <h5>{{item.displayName}} - {{item.handphone}}</h5>
                <h5>{{item.email}}</h5>  
                </div>
                  <div class="col-33" style="float:right; position: relative;" ng-repeat = "datas in statusbaca">
                   
                    <h5>{{datas}}</h5>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now the first problem is i can show the result in html using {{datas}} but when i change to {{datas.stat}} it doesn't show anything. How i can display the stat only in html.
The Second Problem is query display in html only show only latest object of firebase. Not all of object query in firebae. I already tried changing $firebaseArray to $firebaseObject. it still failed.

this is the screen shot of my firebase and the result in the apps.

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the result all value result is false but in firebase one of the user valued true not showed up. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you post the json too?

Comment: @Sajeetharan here's the json from users: {"1vXNeQ1pcVgEs70yp2fyHHDX9OB3":{"displayName":"Samuel Billy","email":"mailmymail@gmail.com","handphone":"085649xxxxx","status":{"15 Sept 2016":{"id":1,"readAt":"0","stat":true},"16 Sept 2016":{"id":2,"stat":false},"17 Sept 2016":{"stat":false},"18 Sept 2016":{"stat":false},"19 Sept 2016":{"stat":false}}},
"r9X1zG5I1bhmiUYxckXgUSOkKnw2":{"displayName":"Cindy","email":"Ndy14@gmail.com","handphone":"087700xxxxxx","status":{"15 Sept 2016":{"id":1,"readAt":"0","stat":false}}}

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue with your style, it works here well,

```
     <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='MyController'>
   <div ng-repeat= "item in users">
            <div class="list card" style="padding:1%;">
                 <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in item.status">
                    {{item.displayName}}
                    <h5>{{key}}</h5>
                     <h5>{{value.stat}}</h5>
                 </div>
            </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wMsIjScOwHLa0wn9iDaW?p=preview)

Comment: it worked if i directly grab it
but i need it nested because i need to grab dates first.and then grab the user data and status of user for detailed view.